# dragging wpf devexpress grid inside of visual studio

Tags: grid, devexpress

Is it not possible to drag a devexpress gridcontrol inside of visual studio?

I added the grid from the toolbox onto the design surface. There doesnt seem to be any way select the grid and move it on the design surface. Am I missing something? Can I only move it by modifying the xaml?

Comment: Is this the 3,000,000th stack overflow question?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the design time support in the DXGrid is very complete and intuitive. As demonstrated on [these screnshots](http://help.devexpress.com/#WPF/CustomDocument8126), there are all standard resizing-adornments available for the DXGrid. It looks like there is some problem in IDE environment or GAC on your side. Thus I suggest you [report this problem directly to DevExpress](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Issues/CreateIssue.aspx?issuetype=bugreport). I believe their support engineers will help you to solve this problem.

Comment: I dont have any issues with resizing the grid, its that I am not able to move it on the design surface with the mouse